# InCallService or ConnectionService for Linphone-Android

Tags: linphone, android-connectionservice

I am working on a Linphone-Android application - and would like the voice calls to appear in the native UI/dialler (a la CallKit in iOS). I believe the two permissions are:

1. InCallService
2. ConnectionService

Has anyone done this before? Any tips/watchouts please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a prototype available on the feature/use_android_native_dialer of the linphone-android repository.

Comment: Thanks @Viish. We did find that and worked with it. However, it seems to crash/stop when the call is disconnected. Any idea how to fix?